# How to handle multiple ports under the same container in kubernetes yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

snippet inside **docker-compose.yml**

```
graphite:
  image: sitespeedio/graphite:1.1.5-3
  ports:
   - "2003:2003"
   - "8080:80"
  restart: always
```

current snippet inside **kube.yml** that needs changes

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: graphite
    image: sitespeedio/graphite:1.1.5-3
    restartPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 2003
```

here, how to write the second mentioned `- "8080:80"` port in kubernetes yaml file?

Comment: Hi,  you need to assign name if you wants to have more ports

Comment: `kubectl  explain pods.spec.containers.ports` will provide more info

Comment: I tried like this 
`ports:
        - name: graphite_one
          containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 80
        - name: graphite_two
          containerPort: 2003
          hostPort: 2003`

Comment: @SureshVishnoi the above is really helpful

Comment: @SureshVishnoi am new to kubernetes; I've another question to ask; do I need to write all the mentioned docker container ports inside deployments -> services as well? https://pastebin.com/gyzp8U7t

Comment: I will create a new question if you knew it

Comment: Deployment compose the podspec and services port map to the pod port

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I tried to manage and fix it; got a clear idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: graphite
    image: sitespeedio/graphite:1.1.5-3
    restartPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 2003
      name: graphite_two 
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: graphite_one
```

will solve your issue.

`kubectl explain pods.spec.containers.ports` provides the detail information about the keys and values

Comment: Great! that helps